# Python ExceptIndex issue?

Tags: python

I have a tab delimited file with 8 columns that has the following context for example

```
Timestamp  Process   TID        Area            Category     EventID    Level           Message         Correlation 

06/21/2014 09:19:02.94  wsstracing.exe (0x068C)                         0x0698  SharePoint Foundation           Tracing Controller Service      5152    Information     Tracing Service started.     

06/21/2014 09:19:09.94  hostcontrollerservice.exe (0x063C)              0x0670  SharePoint Server               Unified Logging Service         b8fx    High            ULS Init Completed (hostcontrollerservice.exe, Microsoft.Office.Server.Native.dll)
```

**http://pastebin.com/f9dmrQtU**

The code I have currently

```
try:
    with open('text.log') as f:
        for l in f:
            print(l.strip().split("\t")[5], end=" "),
            print(l.strip().split("\t")[7], end=" "),
            print(l.strip().split("\t")[8], end="\n")
except IndexError:
    pass
```

Gives me

```
EventID Message  Correlation

5152 Tracing Service started. Press any key to continue . . .
```

As you can see it stops after the first entry because there is nothing in the 8th column anymore.

When what I need is it to print is something like even if there is nothing under the correlation column

```
EventID          Message              Correlation

1124             blahblahblah         blahblah
```

However when I have the following code

```
try:
    with open('text.log') as f:
        for l in f:
            print(l.strip().split("\t")[5], end=" "),
            print(l.strip().split("\t")[7])
```

but prints it in the correct format could anyone provide some assistance?

Comment: Instead of the `pastebin` link post 5-10 lines of data in your question.

Comment: @Ethan-Furman

Okay I did I am not sure how to properly format here however.

Comment: Thank you @jwodder for the proper formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Your `try` is wrapped around the loop, so as soon as one error occurs that `try` block stop executing and jumps to the `except` block, meaning no more iterations can happen.

Instead, you can just put the `try`/`except` inside the for loop.

```
with open('text.log') as f:
    for l in f:
        try:
            print(l.strip().split("\t")[5], end=" "),
            print(l.strip().split("\t")[7], end=" "),
            print(l.strip().split("\t")[8], end="\n")
        except IndexError:
            pass
```

However, since you know that there could be no 8th element, its not really exceptional and will hide errors if you have no 6th or 7th element.

Instead, try and control your logic better with:

```
with open('text.log') as f:
    for l in f:
        x = l.strip().split("\t")[5:] # Grab the elements you want...
        x.pop(1) #... but remove the element you don't
        print(" ".join(x)) # Now print them
```

Comment: I see! This works great thanks for your help! the pop will work in accordance to the elements I select right? So if I want 5-8 and I put 1 it will remove the 6th element?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you wrapping the whole thing in a `try` block?

```
with open('text.log') as f:
    for line in f:
        txt = l.strip().split("\t") # split once
    for col in (5,7,8):
        try:
            _end = "\n" if col == 8 else " "
            print(txt[col], end=_end)
        except IndexError:
            print("\t", end=_end) # print a blank column
```

Answer (score -1):

When you do the `.strip()` you are losing the trailing tabs, so when you `split()` it the line is shorter.  Besides that, you are doing the same operation multiple times.

Try this instead:

```
    with open('text.log') as f:
        for l in f:
            fields = l.split('\t')
            print(fields[5], end=" "),
            print(fields[7], end=" "),
            print(fields[8], end="\n")
```

Comment: This has the same issue, as it will throw the error if element `8` isn't there, preventing further execution.

Comment: By not using `strip` and losing the trailing tab, all eight elements will be there.

Comment: This seems to mess up the formatting?

It is now printing for example

Foundation
Foundation
Foundation

Instead of Sharepoint Foundation

Comment: @user3788715: Sorry -- you still want the `'\t'` in the split.